# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WooGateWayCoreLib\admin\options\functions\Coin_List'

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php namespace WooGateWayCoreLib\admin\options;

/**
 * Class: Coin LIst
 *
 * @package Admin
 * @since 1.0.9
 * @author CoinMarketStats <support@coinmarketstats.online>
 */

if ( ! defined( 'CS_WAPG_VERSION' ) ) {
    die();
}
```

In wordpress plugin WooCommerce Bitcoin / AltCoin Payment Gateway - Version 1.6.2, an error occurs when you try to view or display all coins added.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class
> 'WooGateWayCoreLib\admin\options\functions\Coin_List' not found in
> /*path*/wp-content/plugins/woo-altcoin-payment-gateway/core/admin/options/pages/AllCoins.php:47

Answer (score 0):

I found that Coin_List.php had an error in the "namespace".

> /*PATH*/wp-content/plugins/woo-altcoin-payment-gateway/core/admin/options/functions/Coin_List.php

I changed

```
<?php namespace WooGateWayCoreLib\admin\options;
```

to

```
<?php namespace WooGateWayCoreLib\admin\options\functions;
```

This reflected the correct location of the Coin_List.php file containing the class.